# Draw a Image control on WPF3D to always face the camera

Tags: wpf, 3d, sprite

I've just started playing around with WPF3D and got stuck, here's my scenario:

I've got a couple of sprites implemented using Viewport2DVisual3D with images of trees inside, but when I'm going to move the PerspectiveCamera of the ViewPort3D, I'm going to start seeing the image are flat. How would I go about making all of the about 200 sprites always face the camera after the camera position and lookat point changes.

Appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Your camera looks like:

```
ux  vx  wx  x
uy  vy  wy  y
uz  vz  wz  z
0   0   0   1
```

(`x, y, z`) is the position of the camera and `u, v, w` are the camera vector basis.

Keeping only the position will make your sprites always face the camera. That is

```
1  1  0  x
0  1  0  y
0  0  1  z
0  0  0  1
```

In a combined world-camera matrix you could have combinations of rotation, translation and scaling.
The same approach will work except that you need to keep the scaling.
The scaling in each dimension can be computed as

```
dx = length(u)
dy = length(v)
dz = length(w)
```

and your world-camera transform will be

```
dx  0   0   x
0   dy  0   y
0   0   dz  z
0   0   0   1
```

Another simpler solution is to transform the center of the sprite with the original world-camera matrix (A point won't be affected by rotations).
After transforming the center, draw the sprite quad around it. Multiply the quad side by `dx, dy, dz` if scaling is needed.